# Missing sf::Vector2 class template in SFML

Tags: c++, macos, g++, sfml

I have been going through the tutorials at http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/ and I have ran into a problem in the [using views tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/graphics-views.php).

Here is the section of code I am working on:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){

    // Create instance of Window
    sf::Window App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML Window");

    sf::Vector2 Center(1000, 1000);
    sf::Vector2 HalfSize(400, 300);
    sf::View View1(Center, HalfSize);

    // So on...
```

I am using Mac OSX 10.8 and I am compiling with g++. I get the error message:

```
error: missing template arguments before ‘Center’
```

How can I correct this error?

**EDIT: I somehow read the tutorial wrong. Ment to be Vector2f.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is exactly as the error says, you're missing a type for the `Vector2` template, and judging by constructor of the `View` class,

```
View (const sf::Vector2f &Center, const sf::Vector2f &HalfSize)
```

You want a `Vector2<float>`. These types have already been `typedef`'d for you in the `Vector2.hpp`

```
// Define the most common types
typedef Vector2<int>          Vector2i;
typedef Vector2<unsigned int> Vector2u;
typedef Vector2<float>        Vector2f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the type of a vector, like `sf::Vector2<int>`

Comment: While this is technically correct you should use the typedefs supplied by SFML (sf::Vector2f as stated by others).